# PHP array_merge overwrites itself

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with `array_merge` to make an array of items. The code which I have:

```
$items = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    Log::info($product->orderproduct->idorder_product);

    $items = array_merge($items, [
       'id'          => $product->orderproduct->idorder_product
    ]);
}
Log::info(print_r($items, true));
```

The output is:

```
6
7
['id' => 7]
```

How can I create an array with both id's?

Comment: how many items you have in $products??

Comment: `$items[$id] = $product->orderproduct->idorder_product;` should be sufficient if all your doing is populating an array keyed by ID?

Comment: You can only have one key called 'id'. In other words, each key must be unique.

Comment: According to the manual: `If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.` As an alternative to the answer below, using `array_merge()`, you would would have to merge `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`.

Comment: i think your problem is that you're using the index "id" and overwriting it each time in that loop.
like people already suggested, use $items[] = ['id' => $product->orderproduct->idorder_product];
to create autoincrement numeric index for each array you're adding into $items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what result you expect, so there are 2 options:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    Log::info($product->orderproduct->idorder_product);

    // First
    $items[] = $product->orderproduct->idorder_product;
    // Second
    $items[] = ['id' => $product->orderproduct->idorder_product];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array merge is just another array which add into the bottom of the array.
I think you are misleading us on the result you want to get.

```
$items = array(); / $items = [];
```

you can push the data into array easily by this code

```
$items[] = array(
 'id' => $product->orderproduct->idorder_product,
)
```